# Send asynchronous call in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, nsurlconnection

How can i send a url to a server to add some things in my database?
I was using a NSURLConnection in ios 4, with an asynchronous call, but since ios 5, this method doesn't exist anymore. Apple says i should use:

```
sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
```

But i don't know how to implement this to just send a url to my server and do nothing with the returned data? Or how to send a asynchronous call in ios 5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)

{
     NSLog(@"%@", data);
}];
```